# How to arrange existing java classes into different packages in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio to design an application. I have created a few java classes and want to put them in different packages. I have already created the java classes and have implemented the code inside them. However, now, I want to put them under different packages according to their utility. How can I do that?

In short, I want to go from here:

[image]

to here:

[image]

Sorry for the blurry image, I took it from a video tutorial.

Comment: just drag and drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different things you can do:

1. Drag the java classes and drop them into the package you want
2. Open the app folder from your computer files searcher and just ctl + x the .java files and paste them in the folders you want(creating a new package)
3. Create new java files inside the packages you want and just copy the code from the java files located wrongly. After that delete the java files you don't need.

Hope it helps.